# Hover one item triggers hover of item in a DIFFERENT container

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make a list of links, that when hovered transform the corresponding images below them. 
 
If possible, the opposite would happen when hovering one of the images (triggering the hover effect of the corresponding link).
So far I have only found ways to do this when all items are in the same container.
Here is an outline of what I got:

HTML:

```html
<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="https://...1">LINK 1</a></li> 
  <li><a href="https://...2">LINK 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://...3">LINK 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="images">
  <a href="https://...1">
    <img src="1.png">
  </a> 
  <a href="https://...2">
    <img  src="2.png">
  </a>
  <a href="https://...3">
    <img class="ssoverview" src="3.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.images a img {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    transition: transform .2s;
}

.images a img:hover {
    transition: transform .2s;
    transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

Comment: You've tagged [tag:javascript], but you don't seem to have tried anything using JavaScript to do this...?

Comment: Have you tried adding Id="" and for="" with the controls that are being used.

Comment: You're right, I should have specified: I am new to JavaScript and would love to implement it here, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with CSS alone, but you've also tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), so:

You can do that with `mouseover` and `mouseout`, matching things up by `href`; see comments:

```js
// Remove any existing highlight
function removeHighlight() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".highlight").forEach(el => {
        el.classList.remove("highlight");
    });
}

// Add a highlight to the hovered element (or its LI parent, if any), and any
// matching element by `href` attribute (or its LI parent, if any)
function handler(event) {
    const a = event.target.closest("a");
    if (a && this.contains(a)) {
        removeHighlight();
        // Note: It's important to use `getAttribute` here, not the reflected
        // `href` property, because `getAttribute` will return what's actually
        // in the attribute, but `href` will return a fully-resolved link
        document.querySelectorAll(`[href='${a.getAttribute("href")}']`).forEach(el => {
            const hl = el.parentElement.tagName === "LI" ? el.parentElement : el;
            hl.classList.add("highlight");
            console.log("Added to " + hl.tagName);
        });
    }
}

// Use event delegation to watch for mouseover and mouseout on the containers
const links = document.querySelector(".links");
links.addEventListener("mouseover", handler);
links.addEventListener("mouseout", removeHighlight);
const images = document.querySelector(".images");
images.addEventListener("mouseover", handler);
images.addEventListener("mouseout", removeHighlight);
```

```css
.highlight {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="https://...1">LINK 1</a></li> 
  <li><a href="https://...2">LINK 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://...3">LINK 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="images">
  <a href="https://...1">
    <img src="1.png">
  </a> 
  <a href="https://...2">
    <img  src="2.png">
  </a>
  <a href="https://...3">
    <img class="ssoverview" src="3.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am only able to do the first part where hover the link to scale the corresponding image. **jquery** is required.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.links li a').hover(
    function() {
      var setRelation = $(this).data('relation');
      var aImg = $('.images a').find('#' + setRelation);
      aImg.css('z-index', '1');
      aImg.css('transform', 'scale(1.4)');
    },
    function() {
      var setRelation = $(this).data('relation');
      var aImg = $('.images a').find('#' + setRelation);
      aImg.css('z-index', 'unset');
      aImg.css('transform', 'scale(1.0)');
    });
});
```

```css
a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
}

.images a {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.images a img {
  /* width: 33%; */
  /* float: left; */
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform .2s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.images a img:hover {
  /* transition: transform .2s; */
  /* transform: scale(1.4); */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="links">
  <li><a data-relation="link1" href="https://...1">LINK 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-relation="link2" href="https://...2">LINK 2</a></li>
  <li><a data-relation="link3" href="https://...3">LINK 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="images">
  <a href="https://...1">
    <img id="link1" src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/500">
  </a>
  <a href="https://...2">
    <img id="link2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/500">
  </a>
  <a href="https://...3">
    <img id="link3" class="ssoverview" src="https://picsum.photos/id/13/500">
  </a>
</div>
```